# Select child element CSS

Tags: css, oxygenxml

I am using the Author Mode in Oxygen Editor and I want to create a general CSS for many XML files. I want to be able to select child of a given element, without having to have previously specified the name of the child (only of the parent element), for example:

```
<data-collection>
      <data key="transfer-period" id ="1"/> 
      <data key="communication-profile" id="2">
        <wanCommunication></wanCommunication>
      </data>
</data-collection>
```

Here I would like to select the wanCommuncation child of the data element, without specifying the wanCommunication element.

Does somebody know how this is achieved in CSS?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. And you have a lot of ways to do it. Here are some:

> element:first-child (the first child of the element)
>
> element:last-child (the last child of the element)
>
> element::nth-child(n) (the 'n' child of the element)

These are only a few. You can check the complete list of the CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Take the nth-child(3) of data-collection

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is still not solved. data-collection > data:first-child selects the data element that is first child in the data-collection element, and not the wanCommunication...

Comment: use data:nth-child(3)

Comment: @Goediaz You awnser is correct but your comment is kinda wierd. `document.getElementById('2')::first-child` is neither valid `css` or `javascript`.

Comment: You can't select `:pseudo` elements with `javascript` like that.  Try this in a fiddle or what ever `console.log(document.getElementById('2')::first-child)`. This is a valid selector `document.getElementById('2')` but adding `::first-child` is not! Its not possible at all the select `:pseudo` elements with `javascript` because they are not part of the `DOM`.

Comment: No problem, but you are still wrong ;) `.('#2')` is not a `css` selector. To select an `#id` which starts with a number you have to escape the number using `#\31`. Then its valid `css`. So `#\32 { color: #000 }`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:first-child` selector.

```
data-collection data > :first-child
```

Using the above selector will select every first child in the `data` element which has a parent element `data-collection`.

```css
data-collection data > :first-child {
  background-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<data-collection>
      <data key="transfer-period" id ="1"/>
      <data key="communication-profile" id="2">
        <wanCommunication>Hello :)</wanCommunication>
      </data>
</data-collection>
```